# password_hash() not working with PHP5.5.12

Tags: php, password-encryption, password-hash

I'm trying to add "bcrypt" encryption for my passwords. But when executing the code, i got error like this

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash() in E:\wamp\www\test\passwords\index.php on line 5
```

My code is

```
<?php
$options = ['cost' => 11, 'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)];
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
```

I dont know much about this, just copied the code from the tutorial. Am I missing something?

Comment: You absolutely sure of your PHP version? Maybe try echo-ing out `phpversion()`. FYI, `password_hash()` was introduced in PHP 5.5.0

Comment: Put this as your first line to make sure `phpinfo();` if it's 5.5 you do have.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, i upgraded my php from 5.4.12 to 5.5.12. but it shows 5.4.12 in phpinfo() and 5.5.12 in localhost front page

Comment: Got it... I just upgrade WAMP fully :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why this function doesn't work for you but to be sure confirm you PHP version with **phpinfo()**

Actually, there is an alternative that produces the same hash for PHP >= 5.3.7

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: sorry for the mistake, i upgraded my php from 5.4.12 to 5.5.12. but it shows 5.4.12 in phpinfo() and 5.5.12 in localhost front page :(

Comment: @Arun so do you know why both shows different versions?

Comment: @NIdhin David: I dont know why it happens. Now I just upgrade my wamp fully. The latest version have php 5.5.12